# FullCalendar Google Calendar Angular 2

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I am wondering if anyone has been able to get FullCalendar to work with google calendar implementation? I was successfully able to get the basic FullCalendar to work. When looking at the type definitions it looks like there is no reference to google calendar. If anyone has any ideas it would be a huge help thank you.

Comment: how can we do this `I was successfully able to get the basic FullCalendar to work` in angular 1 please help me...